# (View v) gives me an error and shows a red line

Tags: java, android

i think something is wrong with my java code but i kind quiet figure out what it is.

my view do not seem to be working, it shoes a red line and the small letter v is written in red.
 have a look at my code below and share what you think might be causing the predicament, and how maybe to resolve it.

```
public void displayForTeamA(int score) {
    TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.team_a_score);

    scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(score));

    public void addThreeForTeamA (View v){

        displayForTeamA(3);
```

Comment: Please include the compiler error in your question.

Comment: please send complete code.

Comment: It looks like you forgot the closing } before the next method declaration. You can't have nested methods. Therefore this looks like a simple typo and should be closed as such. If that is not correct, the question should be closed because you are not providing a [mcve].

Comment: Downvoted for lack of responsiveness.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your code properly you are declaring a method inside another method, while this works in Python, it certainly is not how Java works.
`displayForTeamA(int score)` this is your outer method and the method 
`addThreeForTeamA (View v)` should be declared outside this. This should resolve your error.

Comment: yes you're right, itdoes work in Python @Shiredude95

Comment: I declared the method outside and it worked properly., thank you man.